# swi-prolog user login and registration

Tags: prolog

I have user input/ login as following:

```
login:- write('username: '), read(User), nl, write('password: '), read(Pass).
```

and i have a database with usernames and passwords. I use find predicate to get all rows as a list like shown in the code:

```
find(R):-findall(Row, rs('SELECT name FROM patient where name=\'James\'', Row), R).

?- find(R).
 R = [row('James'), row('James'), row('James'), row('James')].
```

Is there a way to use user input from read() and check if that user is in database?

I tried **member(User, R)** but it's not working properly.

I know prolog is not best language for this kind of stuff(login/registration). The reason why I'm doing this is that i'm working on helath care expert system in swi-prolog and i need login and reg for patients.

Is there a why this can be done? I'm new to prolog so im getting stuck on lots of stupid things.

Thanks!

.............
**@gusbro** I tried with **member(row(User)** as you told me:

```
check:-findall(Row, rs('SELECT name FROM patient where name=\'James\'', Row), R),
read(User), member(row(User), R); 
write('wrong username!').
```

But i always get the same no matter what i write:

```
?- check.
|: Bla.
true ;
wrong username!
true.

?- check.
|: James.
true ;
wrong username!
true.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you tried didn't work because you are trying to unify terms of the form row(Atom) with Atom.

It should work fine if you do `member(row(User), R)`.

However, note that in your example it will succeed more than once because you have repeated "rows"...

You might want to consider using `setof/3` instead of `findall/3`, as it will eliminate duplicates from the resulting list (and as a side effect if will fail if there are no matches of the template of setof)

Comment: Thanks for help, do you have any other idea? Because this is not working for me :(

Comment: If you are entering names starting with an uppercase letter you have to enclose them in single quotes, e.g. `|: 'James'.`. Also, reading your rule note that upon backtracking it will eventually tell you 'wrong username'.